# Did DEMOS have a C compiler?

Tags: unix, c, ussr

[DEMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEMOS_(operating_system)) was a Soviet operating system derived from BSD Unix.  The answer to [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19465/10260) shows that the familiar, English-derived BSD commands were essentially the same in DEMOS.

**Did DEMOS have a C compiler?**  If so, was it called `C` (which in Cyrillic has an 's' sound), `K` (which has the 'ck' sound), or something else?

The previous question was about having commands spelled the same, but this does not guarantee that any particular software was installed.

Comment: Just wondering why they should call it anything else? Latin `C` is a different character than Cyrillic `С` (This is not a C - check the encoding :)). Both are present on Cyrillic keyboards. Use is per character set, not glyph.

Comment: The name of the C language is pronounced like the *name* of the letter C, not like the *sound* of the letter C in English. The name of the letter is pronounced differently in many languages that use the Roman alphabet (e.g. "say" in French, "tzee" in German, "chee" in Italian). Why is Russian worth a special question about this?

Comment: Isn't this a straight up duplicate of your other question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DEMOS commands: Cyrillic or Roman letters? Uppercase or lowercase?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/19465/demos-commands-cyrillic-or-roman-letters-uppercase-or-lowercase)

Comment: @OmarL: No, it is not a duplicate of the other question, which is about whether the commands had the same names.  That does not necessarily mean that a C compiler was installed.

Comment: Still sounds to me as pondering around the same issue, now just for a specific command name.

Answer (score 13):

2.9BSD, being a self-hosting operating system, includes all the source code and all the tools necessary to build it. That includes the C compiler, the assembler, and everything. There is no mention anywhere of any of this being renamed for DEMOS, so it's a safe bet that they had the same name.

DEMOS is similar in spirit to something like [Russian Fedora Remix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Fedora_Remix), which is a Linux distribution (everything is named the same, it *is* GNU/Linux after all), but ships with conveniences like a Russian keyboard layout and translations of user-friendly error messages. But you'd expect `make` to still invoke `cc`.

The Latin letter C is unrelated to the Russian letter *С*, even though they look the same and have (sometimes) the same pronunciation. The latter is descended from the Greek sigma, like our S is. C, the programming language, was named for being the next after [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)), so Cyrillic names like *С* or *К* wouldn't really make much sense as a name for C. The language is known as C in Russia, (to be clear, that's a Latin letter C. But sometimes that's transliterated into Cyrillic as "Си", which spells out the sound, "see"). But the compilers are called "GCC", "clang", "cc" or whatever. And as explained in [your other question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19465/10260), the filenames, i.e. the *commands* are the same on DEMOS as on 2.9BSD.

Comment: LOL. Haven't thought about C being the sequence to B - in Cyrillic sorting sequence that's even more funny as the third letter and sequence to `Б` is `В`. So following that logic, A C compiler should be named В in Cyrillic ... ROTFL ... that really made my day :))

Comment: The "C comes after B in the alphabet" (as the C language is a followup to B, itself descended from BCPL) is only half true. The successor to C could be D (next letter in the alphabet) or P (next letter in BCPL).

Comment: @vonbrand: Digital Mars thinks it's D ;-)